# Why does proof by contradiction not work on Rational numbers but only on Irrational numbers?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, irrational-numbers

The most common way to prove the irrationality of a number is to do it by  contradiction.
However, in this proof the contradiction arises from having two numbers, say `p\q` that are assumed to not have any common factors but are later proved to share the number under the radical as a factor. But for instance if the question so arises:

**Is √4 rational or not? Answer with a proof.**

At first glance, it is obviously rational, but assuming I do not know that √4 can be simplified to 2, what would stop me from arriving at irrationality as my conclusion?

This question seems quite trivial and probably stupid. Is this meant to be by definition or am I missing something fundamental to the aforementioned fallacy?

Comment: The step $a$ divides $p^2$ $\implies$ $a$ divides $p$ would not be valid for $a = 4$. This statement is only valid when $a$ is prime.

Comment: @dssknj Even so, how is then this method employed for numbers like 18, 20 for example, to prove that their roots are irrational, despite the fact that they are not prime?

Comment: In the typical irrationality proof where you assume a number of the form $p/q$ you also have $q\neq 1$. This is crucial to the argument. I don't know if your textbook emphasizes this. All such proofs are part of a general theorem: if a rational number $p/q$ is a root of $a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\dots+a_{n-1}x+a_n=0$ where $a_i$ are integers with $a_0\neq 0\neq a_n$ then $p$ divides $a_n$ and $q$ divides $a_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step $a | p^2 \implies a | p$ is only valid when $a$ is prime or **prime factorisation of $a$ do not have repeated primes**.

Now proving square root of composite non perfect squares, irrational is a little different.For e.g.

Let $$\sqrt{18} = \frac{p}{q}$$
$$18q^2 = p^2 \implies 2 | p^2 \text{and}\; 3 | p^2$$
$$\implies 2|p \;\text{and}\; 3|p \implies 6|p$$
$$\text{Let}\; p = 6m$$ then 
$$18q^2 = 36m^2 \implies q^2 = 2m^2 \implies 2 | q$$ Hence, contradiction.

$\sqrt{18}$ is not rational.

Comment: This explains it! Can't believe I missed that although I haven't properly studied divisibility yet.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{a}$, where $a$ isn't a perfect square, goes by contradiction. Assume it is rational, i.e.:

$\begin{equation*}
   \sqrt{a} = \dfrac{p}{q}
\end{equation*}$

where $\gcd(p, q) = 1$ (the fraction is in lowest terms) and $q \ne 1$ ($a$ is not a square). Then:

$\begin{align*}
   a
     &= \frac{p^2}{q^2} \\
   a q^2
     &= p^2
\end{align*}$

Now $p^2$ divides the right hand side, so it must divide the left hand side. But $p$ has no factors in common with $q$, so $\gcd(p^2, q^2) = 1$ also; so it divides $a$. That means $a = b p^2$:

$\begin{align*}
   b p^2 q^2
     &= p^2 \\
   b q^2
     &= 1
\end{align*}$

This is impossible, $q \ne 1$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $ \sqrt{4}>0$.

assume that $$\sqrt{4}=\frac pq$$ with $$\text{gcd(p,q)}=1$$
then
$$p^2=4q^2$$
hence $ p$ is even with $ p=2p'$.

thus
$$p'^2=q^2$$
and
$$p'=q \text{ or }  \sqrt{4}=2$$

there is no contradiction.

Comment: With reference to my question, I meant for when you do the same things step by step  WITHOUT using the fact that the number is a perfect square. Here, you have declared `p` to be even. Even though that is correct, 2 is taken as the common factor instead of 4, as you would in a contradiction proof, which is where I am getting confused since at the end I can say that both p and q share 4 as a factor, contradicting my assumption and therefore declare root 4 to be irrational!